# Property file update not working properly for ":"

Tags: java

I want to update the property in properties file in java. But it is working for the String contains ':'. for example "C:\Kamlesh" it writes "C\:\Kamlesh" code as follows

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("D:\\test\\prop.properties");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(in);
in.close();

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:\\test\\prop.properties");
props.setProperty("filename", "C" +":" + "\\america");
props.store(out, null);
out.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's expected, because `:` is a separator (it can be used instead of `=`). So it's escaped. Reading the properties will automatically unescape it.